# Efficient methods of searching vectors for specific int's that meet a condition?

Tags: c++, algorithm, search

I'm trying to write an efficient operation to search through a vector, specifically identify the existence of three int's (A1, A2, A3) where A1 > A2 && A2 < A3.

So given A {5,3,1,2,3}, the operation with output: [3,1,2], [3,2,3],[5,1,3], [5,1,2]

The obvious approach would be to use three nested loops:

```
int my_function()
{
  std::vector<int> A {3,5,3,1,2,3};
  for(auto IT1 = A.begin(); IT != A.end(); IT1++)
  {
    for(auto IT2 = IT1 + 1; IT2 != A.end(); IT2++)
    {
      for(auto IT3 = IT2 + 1; IT3 != A.end(); IT3++)
      {
        if(*IT1 > *IT2 && *IT3 > *IT2)
        {
          //Do stuff
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Clearly this is very inefficient, are there any known ways of performing an operation such as this in a single loop? Or more efficiently than three nested loops?

Comment: You might move `*IT1 > *IT2` outside of `IT3` loop.

Comment: `A2 > A2`? U Wot?

Comment: Do you want any, all or first valid triplet ?

Comment: @Jarod42 all valid triplets

Comment: How about sorting the data first...? I'm surprised nobody mentioned that until now. No need for O(n^3)

Comment: Presumably the triplets don't need to be consecutive elements?

Comment: @deviantfan why would you change the ordering , if the triplets are to be formed from given set of data ?

Comment: @Bathsheba triplets do not need to be consecutive elements

Comment: In that case, you're stuck with O(NNN),

Comment: Is the range of the integer values limited?

Comment: (Ah, now I read the example and understood that the order *is* relevant)

Comment: Why is `[2,1,3]` not valid output for your example? The problem definition seems incomplete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find all such triplets, nothing is asymptotically faster since the number of such triplets can be up to `O(N^3)`.

**UP:** Hovewer, if you somehow have a guarantee that there're not so much such triplets (let's say you have `T = o(N^3)` of them), you can write a more efficient algorithm.

Let's iterate through all the elements of the array and try place current element in the middle of the triplet. To do so, we need to maintain two ordered sets of values: one of all the values to the left of current, and sencond - to the right. Here's the code:

```
// Initialization
std::multiset<int> left;                      // empty set
std::multiset<int> right(A.begin(), A.end()); // set of all elements in A
// Iterations
for (int x : A) {
    right.erase(x);
    for (auto l = left.rbegin(); l != left.rend() && *l > x; ++l) {
        for (auto r = right.rbegin(); r != right.rend() && *r > x; ++r) {
            // Do stuff with triplet *l, x, *r.
        }
    }
    left.insert(x);
}
```

The complexity of such solution is `O(T + NlogN)`, which is much less than `O(N^3)` if `T` is small. The downside is that the triplets are processed in a different order.

Comment: hi, what does O(N^3) mean?

Comment: @LorenceHernandez This is big-o notation for time complexity, see http://bigocheatsheet.com

Comment: @LorenceHernandez It means that the number of operations the program performes is proportional to N^3. That is, if N doubles, the program run time typically multiplies by 8. Typically, such asymptotics is ok for N up to several hundreds to several thousands, depending on a particular program and hardware. For strict definition, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation